# Changing font size of UITextView by UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uislider

I need to change the `UITextView`'s font Size according to the value of `UISlider`.

Written in `viewDidLoad()`

`tvVarse.text=strTextToShow; //tvVarse is the UITextViewOutlet, strTextToShow is the text to be shown on textView`

Checked:

1. Both `UITextView` and `UISlider`'s Outlet is Connected.
2. `UITextVIew` Behavior "Selectable" is checked in outlet.
3. Given `UISlider` Minimum Value is 13 and Maximum Value is 25 in
   Outlet.

EDIT:
Structure of `UIView`

[image]

I have tried following codes:

Try 1:

```
- (IBAction)sliderTap:(UISlider*)sender //Value changed action for UISlider
{
    tvVarse.font = [tvVarse.font fontWithSize:sender.value];
}
```

Try 2:

```
- (IBAction)sliderTap:(UISlider*)sender //Value changed action for UISlider
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    tvVarse.font = [tvVarse.font fontWithSize:sender.value];

    });
}
```

Try 3:

```
- (IBAction)sliderTap:(UISlider*)sender //Value changed action for UISlider
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    tvVarse.text=strTextToShow;
    tvVarse.font = [tvVarse.font fontWithSize:sender.value];
    [tvVarse setNeedsLayout];
    [tvVarse setNeedsDisplay];
    });
}
```

Try 4:

```
- (IBAction)sliderTap:(UISlider*)sender //Value changed action for UISlider
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    tvVarse.font = [tvVarse.font fontWithSize:sender.value];
    tvVarse.text=strTextToShow;
    [tvVarse setNeedsLayout];
    [tvVarse setNeedsDisplay];
    });
}
```

Try 5:

```
- (IBAction)sliderTap:(UISlider*)sender //Value changed action for UISlider
{
    tvVarse.font = [tvVarse.font fontWithSize:sender.value];
    tvVarse.text=strTextToShow;
}
```

Now the funny Point is When I am Providing Other text, it is Working i.e

Working but different small text:

```
- (IBAction)sliderTap:(UISlider*)sender //Value changed action for UISlider
{
    tvVarse.text=@"My name is Manab";
    tvVarse.font = [tvVarse.font fontWithSize:sender.value];
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why these are not working?

Comment: What's the iOS version ?

Comment: iOS 9.2 for iPhone, tested in Simulator vs 9.2

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

***First set the font and then write text...***

```
tvVarse.font = [tvVarse.font fontWithSize:sender.value];
tvVarse.text=strTextToShow;
```

Comment: Not Working @Fahim Parkar, I have tried that also when I was doing Try 4, Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I have tried with this funny Trick (Wonderfully it is working):

```
- (IBAction)sliderTap:(UISlider*)sender
{
    tvVarse.text=@"";//Just provided blank text before loading textview again
    tvVarse.font = [tvVarse.font fontWithSize:sender.value];
    tvVarse.text=strTextToShow;

}
```

But I don't know why it is working!!